# Vim triple button combinations

Tags: key-bindings

In vim, many keys in normal mode perform an action only when appended by another character. For example `g`, by itself, doesn't do anything. But `gg` goes to the top of the page, `gt` goes to the next tab, and `gT` goes to the previous tab. This is an example of a double character combo where the first character is sort of behaving like a verb I guess, and the second character specifies the action.

I'd like to have a button in normal mode that waits for *two* additional characters to specify a behavior/mapping. Is this possible? This would solve two of my problems: firstly, it would drastically expand the number of empty/available bindings (since there are many more unique triple character combos than double) so I'm free to create as many mappings as I desire. Secondly, it makes sense from a syntactical perspective to allow more specificity of behavior in vim, for the users who want it.

For example, if i want to enter in a template empty docstring under a function's definition based on the language (since docstrings have a different syntax in different languages), the first character can be `i` for insert, then `d` for docstring, and then e.g. `p` for python or `c` for c++.

Comment: you sure can!

but maybe you can give an example?

Comment: Added an example:)

Comment: Be advised, though, that choosing something like `i` as the first character of your mapping may not be desirable as when you just want to go from Normal mode to Insert (i.e. by hitting `i`) you will encounter a small delay (whose length is configurable). Most people prefer to start with an unbound key (and that usually means their leader key).

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't map ```i``` as the first character. The first character would probably be the leader (so total of four characters). Your comment gives some insight though, so when you create a mapping in .vimrc in which a character waits for more characters, vim will automatically detect that and implement a delay for that character?

Comment: See help for these settings for details `'timeout'`, `'ttimeout'`, `'timeoutlen'`, `'ttimeoutlen`. It's for those times when what happens next is ambiguous to vim since there may be a mapping x as well as a mapping xx. Or xy and xz. In those cases what happens when you've just hit x.

Comment: `:h map-typing`, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim mappings you create can have arbitrary lengths. Typically you'll try to make them short, since the shorter they are, the easier to type.

Three character mappings are fairly common though. For example, many plug-ins that comment and uncomment lines (such as [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) or [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter)) use `gcc` to toggle comment on the current line.

As another example, the [SpaceVim](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim) distribution sets up many 3 or 4 character mappings, most of them starting with `<Space>` (or `SPC`) which is SpaceVim's "leader" key. For example, `SPC c l` to toggle comment on lines, `SPC i l p` to insert a "lorem-ipsum" paragraph (of filler text), `SPC x a =` to align on the "=" symbol, `SPC b n` to switch to the next buffer, etc. Since SpaceVim creates so many mappings, its flagship feature is actually a hierarchical menu displaying the next choices, triggered by the `SPC` at the start of the mapping, to help users navigate so many possible choices. (SpaceVim also displays an interactive menu for `g` and `z`, which are Vim's native multi-character prefixes for mappings.)

> If I want to enter in a template empty docstring under a function's definition based on the language (since docstrings have a different syntax in different languages), the first character can be `i` for insert, then `d` for docstring, and then e.g. `p` for Python or `c` for C++.

As mentioned, using `i` as a prefix is not a good idea, since it's already a one-character command.

If you're assuming these would come after a leader (possibly the one you set to `mapleader`, which you access in mappings with `<Leader>`), then it's fine.

But: do you really need both `i` and `d`? Do you have another action to do on a docstring other than inserting it? Shouldn't `<Leader>d` perhaps suffice? (But then, if you have many many mappings, you might really need another level of mappings.)

Regarding supporting multiple languages, you should probably implement a *single* mapping to insert a docstring and have it insert the appropriate format based on the type of file. Vim can recognize file types (or you can set them explicitly) through the [`'filetype'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27filetype%27) option.

See [`:help filetype-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_43.txt.html#filetype-plugin) for help creating a plug-in for a specific file type, which you can use to create sets of similar mappings implementing the same feature (such as inserting a docstring) for each relevant file type.

For inserting boilerplate, consider also the many snippet plug-ins available in Vim, which are perfect for this kind of task and typically allow you to define snippets per file type (so, again, you can use a single trigger for docstring and implement it differently for each language you care about.) Snippet plug-ins normally expand snippets from *insert* mode, so you usually don't need to reserve normal mode mappings (and deal with deep mappings, with long character sequences), which addresses another motivation you mentioned in the question.

Comment: And if you have lots of mapping prefixes, you can use my [popsikey](https://github.com/popsikey) for a simpler HUD then SpaceVim’s (im pretty sure it doesn’t support multiple prefix levels yet, and I’m not sure i have the motivation to make it do so)

Comment: I do need both ```i``` and ```d```, ```i``` is for insert, and sometimes I would like to insert other things, such as unit test templates. so ```(leader)iup``` would be inserting a python unit test, for example. I have <Leader>d already mapped to deleting to black hole register. Regarding creating a plugin based on file type, I'll look more into it!

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh I really recommend you look into snippets... I really like [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and you can find a nice snippet library at [honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) that is ready to use and will get you started... And snippet managers such as UltiSnips make it easy for you to create more of your own snippets.

Comment: See, for example, [`testcase`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/c609efe753ccc2f2631908149e94febc0b257052/UltiSnips/python.snippets#L676) and [`doc`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/c609efe753ccc2f2631908149e94febc0b257052/UltiSnips/python.snippets#L703) for a docstring.

Comment: @filbranden I looked into them, super useful. Thanks! Could you also add in your answer than if vim detects that there is a binding that starts with the same pattern the user inputs it will wait to see if the user will continue to input the rest of that pattern, otherwise it will apply the existing input? This explains how triple button combinations are possible in vim.

Comment: :h 'timeout', 'ttimeout', 'timeoutlen', 'ttimeoutlen', 'map-typing'